# Find a domain D and elements a, b, c ∈ D such that GCD(a,b) exists but GCD(ac,bc) does not.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am not sure if I understand it correctly but isn't that very simple we can take gcd(2,3) = 1, and our c = 0, and gcd(0,0) does not exist?

Or my thinking process is wrong?

Comment: That's not right. $\gcd(0,0)=0$.

Comment: Many authors leave gcd$(0, 0)$ undefined. I think it depends on the definition of gcd that is given in your course.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Think of it this way: "$x\mid y$" is defined to be equivalent to "$y=xz$ for some $z\in D$". But $0=0z$ for all $z\in \Bbb Z$, so $0\mid 0$ (despite $\frac{0}{0}$ being undefined in this context). Divisors of $a$ are less than or equal to $a$, for all $a$. It follows that

$$\gcd(0,0)=0.$$